# Jenkins Version 2.332.3 "Configure System" save/apply button not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack, jenkins-update

I am on Jenkins version 2.332.3 and I am unable to apply/save any changes made in configure system. I am attempting to add slack configurations.
-The "Slack Notification" plugin has been installed on Jenkins
-The "JenkinsCI" app/integration has been added to a slack channel.

*I am able to test the connection and receive the message in the designated Slack channel
*I am also able to add post-build actions within the specific job with no issues

However I'm unable to apply/save the changes in the configure system menu. When I run a test build, it's failing with this error message:

FATAL: the credential with the provided ID (null) could not be found and no token was specified

The fatal message is due to my configurations not saving on the configure systems page.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Do the save/apply buttons in other places work? There seems to be a variety of different causes for this problem. Try uninstalling and re-installing the plugin, as well as updating Jenkins and existing plugins.

Comment: Yes, the save/apply buttons work everywhere else except in configure settings. I have updated all plugin. Deleted the slack notification plugin and redownloaded it. 

It will not work. Im thinking the issue is with the Jenkins UI itself.